# NARX implementation using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a simple NARX network in keras (backend Tensoflow). I am building the model by subclassing `tf.keras.Model`. A NARX network can be trained as a simple feedforward network (series-parallel architecture), therefore I did not have any problem with this definition. However for prediction I need to close the loop and give back the output as input to the model. How can I modify the network so that it is able to make predictions and forecastings?

Here is a minimal version of the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numPreviousSteps = 8
inputShape = (None, numPreviousSteps + 2)

class Narx(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Narx, self).__init__(name='narx')
        self.dense = keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=inputShape,
                                        activation=keras.activations.tanh)
        self.outputLayer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=keras.activations.linear)

    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        if (training):
            x = self.dense(inputs)
            return self.outputLayer(x)
        else: # TODO: what should the network do when used for prediction
            x = self.dense(inputs)
            return self.outputLayer(x)


model = Narx()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.training.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001),
              loss=tf.losses.mean_squared_error,
              metric=tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error)

# input data generation
numTsSamples = 1000

# time series to learn from
y = np.random.random((numTsSamples + numPreviousSteps + 1,))
x = np.random.random((numTsSamples,)) # exogenous input

# creation of tapped delay
data = [np.roll(y, -i)[:numTsSamples] for i in range(numPreviousSteps, -1, -1)]
data = [x] + data

# training data
data = np.stack(data, axis=1)

# expected results
yNext = y[numPreviousSteps : -1]

# model training
model.fit(data, yNext)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to run NARX in python?

Comment: No I did not. I ended up using tf.contrib.timeseries, but that is now deprecated.

Comment: Do you have an implementation of both training and prediction/forecasting in tf.contrib.timeseries that you could share? I'd be interested in seeing the implementation even if it is deprecated.

Comment: You can find some examples in this GitHub project https://github.com/hzy46/TensorFlow-Time-Series-Examples

Comment: That repo seems to only have univariate AR models or multivariate LSTM examples, not multivariate AR models (i.e. exogenous NARX) as examples right? I'm mainly just interested in NARX examples.

Comment: Is this solved? Is there anyone have some solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can Implement your ARX Model using Gekko:
https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries

I have the same Problem with the feedback Loop. If you are only interested in whether your model can simulate the system behavior, the following code is sufficient.
its from:
https://aleksandarhaber.github.io/machine_learning/2018/12/20/mlp-sys-identification.html

```
predict_time=X_test.shape[0]-2*past

Y_predicted_offline=np.zeros(shape=(predict_time,1))
Y_past=network_prediction[0:past,:].T
X_predict_offline=np.zeros(shape=(1,2*past))

for i in range(0,predict_time):
    X_predict_offline[:,0:past]=X_test[i+2*past,0:past]
    X_predict_offline[:,past:2*past]=Y_past    
    y_predict_tmp= model.predict(X_predict_offline)
    Y_predicted_offline[i]=y_predict_tmp
    Y_past[:,0:past-1]=Y_past[:,1:]
    Y_past[:,-1]=y_predict_tmp

error_offline=Y_predicted_offline-Y_test[past:-past,:]
error_offline_percentage=LA.norm(error_offline,2)/LA.norm(Y_test,2)*100

#plot the offline prediction and the real output
plt.plot(Y_test[past:-past,:],'b',label='Real output')
plt.plot(Y_predicted_offline, 'r', label='Offline prediction')
plt.xlabel('Discrete time steps')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()    
plt.savefig('prediction_offline.png')
#plt.show()

plt.figure()
#plot the absolute error (offline and online)
plt.plot(abs(error_offline),'r',label='Offline error')
plt.plot(abs(error),'b',label='Online error')
plt.xlabel('Discrete time steps')
plt.ylabel('Absolute prediction error')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()   
plt.savefig('errors.png')
#plt.show()
```

You can find the explanation in video form there:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=badm72VMwCE